# How I can check in test if response get view with or without form?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Like in title, I don't know how I can test if in response is view with or without form because in my view user getting form only if request.user.is_authenticated.

```
##views.py

def product_detail(request, id, slug):

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug,)
    comments = product.comments.all()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment.product = product
                new_comment.nick = get_object_or_404(User, id=str(request.user.id))
                form.save()
                return redirect('product_detail', id=product.id, slug=product.slug)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()

        return render(request, 'shop/product/Product_detail.html',
                      {'product': product, 'form': form, 'comments': comments})

    else:
        return render(request, 'shop/product/Product_detail.html',
                      {'product': product, 'comments': comments})
```

I have view test to check if view loads but both authenticated and not authenticated users have acces to this view only difference is that not authenticated users are getting view without form and i dont know how to test this.

```
##test_views.py

    def test_call_view_loads(self):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
        response = self.client.get(f'/shop/{product.id}/{product.slug}/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'shop/product/Product_detail.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the context used from the [`response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses) returned by the Test Client.

```
self.assertTrue('form' in response.context)
```

However, this should not be how you test if a user is logged in or not; Only whether or not certain context variables are being passed to the template.

Comment: Yes, I know, to check if user is logged or not I have self.assertTrue(login) and login=self.client.login(...). I just want to show in test that if user isn't authenticated then form won't be returned

Answer (score 1):

Find your Form Class in your context :

```
self.assertIsInstance(response.context['form'], CommentForm) #find your form in context
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `self.client.login(username='user', password='pass')` inside your `test_call_view_loads` like this:

```
from django.test.client import Client

def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user('user', 'user@email.com', 'pass')


def test_call_view_loads_loggined_user(self):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    self.client.login(username='user', password='pass')  # login the user
    response = self.client.get(f'/shop/{product.id}/{product.slug}/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'shop/product/Product_detail.html')
    self.assertTrue('form' in response.context)  # for check that is form in context or not
```